# iframe (javascript) + correct url

Tags: javascript, html, url, iframe

i have a domain full-ops.com

that i transferred to another host, but it takes 5days to transfer it.
So what i want to do on my old host is make an iframe that loads in the site from the new host. so that the user can type in full-ops.com and go to the new site.

but is it possible through javascript or any other thing to have the correct url from the iframed site in the browsers url bar?

so the new host url is

http://89.31.97.5/~fullops/index.php

but if i go to a category on the new site the url could be

http://89.31.97.5/~fullops/index.php/equipment-tactique/medic.html

is it possible with the iframe to get the url like this

http://full-ops.com/index.php/equipment-tactique/medic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the address bar of the parent from inside the iFrame but, the browser will go to that address and you cannot prevent that. It is a security feature.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your issue, when I answer.

The issue I think you are having is worrying about what people will think when they look at the url and see an ipaddress instead of your company name.

It is only 5 days (which seams a bit long to me), so I wouldnt worry, I would suggest simply having your old site redirect to the ipaddress of your new site until you get it sorted.

Once your hosting has taken full effect you could put something in your new site to detect when people are entering the site on an ip and redirect them to the friendly named url.

Hope this is what you are after.

Cheers